# Best 3D object recognition package

Tags: ros, object-recognition, 3d-object-recognition, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I came across few object detection/recognition packages in ros

1. tabletop_objects
2. steder11icra
3. roboearth
4. find_object

I find some of them are built on cturtle and when i try to checkout these packages they accompany with lot of other packages of cturtle along with them. I have ros-electric and would like to recognize some objects like laptop, bottle and books etc using 3D pointclouds from Kinect. So can someone suggest the best package that is stable and working.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12444/best-3d-object-recognition-package/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on 2012-03-29**:
hey we are also working on object detection/identification using 3D pointclouds from kinect. so can you suggest the best package/database for this purpose..?  thank!

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-30**:
As of now i am using PCL and writing a simple package myself to recognize object. You may check the documentation of PCL and its tutorials for the same.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2018-07-12**:
hi, it's that any suggestion or recommendation for me to lean how to detect the a object? and I'm more comfortable with python......so any suggestion for me? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current tabletop detector works well for well-separated, rotationally-symmetric objects on a flat surface such as a table.  It won't work for laptops and books unless they're in exactly the same orientation as in the database (tabletop detection is only doing 2D ICP).

TOD works well for highly textured objects (from views in which the texture is actually visible and not just a tiny patch of fuzzy pixels that humans can't even make out), but I wouldn't say that it's quite stable yet.  Should be available and stable for Fuerte Turtle.

Can't say about the others, I haven't tried them.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2012-01-09**:
http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-09**:
TOD seems to be there only in diamondback. Am i missing something here.

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2012-01-09**:
tabletop detector works with either Kinect or narrow stereo; TOD requires Kinect.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-09**:
Does it work with Kinect as the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran roboearth on electric and was quite happy with it. The good thing is that you can easily teach your own objects to be recognized. The recognition success rate was not as high as I expected though.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-22**:
Ok thanks :)

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-12-22**:
I was recognizing a specific connector used in a nuclear plant :) (which I learnt using their excellent learning node)

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-22**:
could you tell me what objects worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd also suggest to have a look at VFH-based matching: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php#vfh-recognition
We at TUM are rather happy with it.

For the textured objects Willow's TOD seems to be very promising (though I am still evaluating it): http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried both roboearth and the tabletop detector and I think the tabletop detector works better at the moment in terms of recognizing the objects. However, adding models into a local database is easier in roboearth than in tabletop, but when I tried roboearth it often failed to find the marker template so a model could not be created. If you have to choose between these two, I'd recommend using the tabletop detector because of the higher success rate, but you'll have to find out how to add objects properly to the database (I'm also looking into that now).

---

Originally posted by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) with karma: 205 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on 2012-01-04**:
I also thought about doing something like that, but I haven't tried it. Roboearth creates models as pointclouds, while tabletop uses the ply format. Unfortunately, I don't know any applications that are able to convert pointcloud models to ply models.

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2012-01-04**:
I wonder if a model created with roboearth could easily be inserted in the household database. Someone already tried this ?

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on 2012-01-03**:
Yeah I also posted something there, insert_model.cpp worked for me but the model I created was probably faulty. I think I have to create a new model using 3DSom or something alike. I'll post a new question on the forum regarding this, thanks for your comment!

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2012-01-03**:
Take a look at this question : http://answers.ros.org/question/388/household_objects_database-new-entries, it may help you adding new entries to the database.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the answers are outdated. Please completely forget ork, you will just waste your time on it for poor results on all pipelines.

Use [v4r](https://rgit.acin.tuwien.ac.at/v4r/v4r_ros_wrappers) for a solution at least 10 times better than everything mentioned before. Install it from debians and use the multishot version. It works with textured an untextured objects (SIFT and SHOT based) .

A neural network alternative is [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) but it has no pose estimation afaik.

Another try is [this package](https://github.com/cagbal/ros_people_object_detection_tensorflow/blob/master/README.md)

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Danilo_BR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32625/danilo_br/) on 2019-04-16**:
I can't compile v4r on Ubuntu Xenial, tryed all branches and it seems that it requires Boost 1.48 but default to Xenial is 1.58... Do you know exactly which version of v4r and v4r_ros_wrappers to install? it looks like their project is paused or something.

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2019-04-16**:
Yes unfortunately the project looks dead. I remember that I also had problems building v4r. Have you tried installing from debians as described in the readme? https://rgit.acin.tuwien.ac.at/v4r/v4r/blob/master/Readme.md

**Comment by [Danilo_BR](https://answers.ros.org/users/32625/danilo_br/) on 2019-04-23**:
Yes, it installs but when I start the camera it gives an error about shared pointers in the boost library.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2019-06-16**:
Not an answer, but I have rejuvenated this question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/325930/ork-replacement-package/)